# Внешняя компонента 1с на с#. Освобождение COM-объектов

Tags: c#, 1с, com

Внешняя компонента реализует `IInitDone` и `ILanguageExtender`. В метод `Init()` передается указатель на `IDispatch`. Пока его не трогаю, объект компоненты создается и завершается корректно, т.е. при завершении работы 1c как положено вызывается метод `Done()`.

Теперь создаю "объект 1с", так как нужно вернуть из компоненты значения не базовых типов:

```
var obj1c= V7Data.V7Object.GetType().InvokeMember("AppDispatch", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, V7Data.V7Object, null);
int refCount = Marshal.Release(Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(obj1c));
```

Так вот, при попытке завершить работу 1с, она зависает. Смотрю отладчиком - `Marshal.Release` не уменьшает число ссылок на объект, `refCount` остается неизменным, сколько бы раз я не вызвал `Release`. (Пробовал в цикле).

Собственно, что я делаю не так? Как побороть зависания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заработало в таком виде:

```
   public void Done()
    {
        if (_obj1c != null)
        {
            var obj1cPtr = Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(_obj1c);
            int rc = Marshal.Release(obj1cPtr);
            while (rc > 0)
            {
                rc = Marshal.Release(obj1cPtr);
            }
            _obj1c = null;
        }

        if (_obj1c != null)
        {
            var connectionPtr = Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(V7Data.V7Object);
            int rc = Marshal.Release(connectionPtr);
            while (rc > 0)
            {
                rc = Marshal.Release(connectionPtr);
            }
            V7Data.V7Object = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

`_obj1c` пришлось вынести в приватное поле основного класса, который реализует `IInitDone`.

`V7Object`- это статическое свойство класса V7Data.